# How to format date string in java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

Hi i have the following string:2012-05-20T09:00:00.000Z
and i want to format it to be like 20/05/2012, 9am

How to do so in java?

Thanks

Comment: Modern answer: use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. `OffsetDateTime.parse("2012-05-20T09:00:00.000Z").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu"))`. Or even better, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to first `parse()` `String` to `Date` and then `format()` `Date` to `String`

Answer (score 86):

If you are looking for a solution to your particular case, it would be:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").parse("2012-05-20T09:00:00.000Z");
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, Ka").format(date);
```

Comment: Date must be java.util.Date, with java.sql.Date it doesn't work (just a note)

Answer (score 5):

```
package newpckg;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class StrangeDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // string containing date in one format
        // String strDate = "2012-05-20T09:00:00.000Z";
        String strDate = "2012-05-20T09:00:00.000Z";

        try {
            // create SimpleDateFormat object with source string date format
            SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'.000Z'");

            // parse the string into Date object
            Date date = sdfSource.parse(strDate);

            // create SimpleDateFormat object with desired date format
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDestination = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy, ha");

            // parse the date into another format
            strDate = sdfDestination.format(date);

            System.out
                    .println("Date is converted from yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'.000Z' format to dd/MM/yyyy, ha");
            System.out.println("Converted date is : " + strDate.toLowerCase());

        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            System.out.println("Parse Exception : " + pe);
        }
    }
}
```