# Get date and time of device without any punctuation marks

Tags: android, datetime, punctuation

I want to get the current time and date of the device on my android app, but without any punctuation marks.

I mean like: 

05112016

and

1946

How can I do that on my android app?

**EDIT 1#**:
The question isn't a duplicate, since the answer in the suggested duplicate isn't what I'm asking. When I run the code from the answer and delete any punctuation marks I get "Nov52016101232" instead of what I want which is "05112016101232".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date string in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046053/how-to-format-date-string-in-java)

Comment: @Andreas It's not a duplicate since it's not what I want. I want to get a clear string without anything. Not slashes, not dots, not dashes and not anything else. Just numbers.

Comment: Yes, so you give a format string requesting that! You're still just asking how for format the date as a string, aren't you?

Comment: Can't you can use replaceAll method to remove the punctuation marks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to achieve this.

```
//date
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
 sdf.format(new Date());

 //time 
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm", Locale.ENGLISH);
 sdf.format(new Date());
```